# How to run Cron on Google Cloud Daily at 00:00

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron, gcloud

I have a cron job that runs for every 24hrs

```
- description: "automatic renew a user after trial"
  url: /api/recursub
  schedule: every 24 hours
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
  timezone: Europe/Madrid
```

But I want to schedule it run at 12 midnight everyday.

I saw something similar on the documentation

```
cron:
- description: "monday morning mailout"
  url: /mail/weekly
  schedule: every monday 09:00
  timezone: Australia/NSW
```

Is it possible to run schedule daily like this

> schedule: daily 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)

```
[TYPE]: Custom intervals can include the every prefix to define a repetitive interval, or you can define a specific list of days in a month:
To define a repetitive interval you can use the every prefix.

Examples:

schedule: every day 00:00
schedule: every monday 09:00
```